# Bootstrap 4 radio button color in edge browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend

For radio buttons in Bootstrap 4, the color of the radio button is blue in Chrome and black in Edge.

Is there a way to change it to blue in Bootstrap?

In Chrome,
[image]

In Edge,
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the color of radio buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons)

Comment: Or this? [How can I style radio buttons with different colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843685/bootstrap-radio-buttons-with-different-colors)

Comment: If Bootstrap provided a way to color radio buttons you'd see it in [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/#checkboxes-and-radios). You'll need to apply custom CSS. However, there are UX and accessibility implications from doing so. It's sometimes best to leave controls in default style. You could also consider using a [button toggle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/#toggle-states).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an accent color in CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    accent-color: green;
}
```