# Change color of Radiobutton with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

Currently I am working on a project with React and Bootstrap. Now I want to customize the radiobuttons to fit in with the other colors.
Is there a way to change the color of a radiobutton with Bootstrap if it is checked? 
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843685/how-can-i-style-radio-buttons-with-different-colors does this help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I style radio buttons with different colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843685/how-can-i-style-radio-buttons-with-different-colors)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using CSS

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  /* remove standard background appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* create custom radiobutton appearance */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 6px;
  /* background-color only for content */
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
  background-color: #e7e6e7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* appearance for checked radiobutton */
input[type="radio"]:checked {
  background-color: #93e026;
}

/* optional styles, I'm using this for centering radiobuttons */
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
  <label for="radio1">Button1</label>
</div>
<div class="flex">
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" />
  <label for="radio2">Button2</label>
</div>
```